# Enable html form field one by one

Tags: javascript, php, html

I Have a form with field ABA11,ABA12,ABA13........Which is used to update the data. In this form all the field should be remained in disabled mode except the first field ABA11 initially.once the ABA11 field is filled then only ABA12 will be enabled to enter data.Once the data is entered and it is saved in data base after that this filled should also be in disable mode.And this process to be continued for other field

```
<?php
$status11=disabled;
if(htmlentities($result->aba11)==null){
    $status11=enabled;
}
?>
<td><input type="datetime-local"  name="aba11" id="aba11" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba11);?>" class="form-control" <?php echo $status11?> ></td> 
<?php
$status12=disabled;
if(htmlentities($result->aba11)!=null and htmlentities($result->aba12)== null ){
    $status12=enabled;
}
?>
<td><input type="datetime-local" name="aba12" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba12);?>" class="form-control" <?php echo $status12?>></td>
<td><input type="text" name="aba13" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba13);?>" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class= "col-md-1.5" align="centre">0.0.1M NaOH</th>
<th class= "col-md-2" align="centre">60 Degree C</th>

<td><input type="datetime-local"  name="aba21"onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba21);?>" class="form-control" ></td> 
<td><input type="datetime-local" name="aba22" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba22);?>" class="form-control" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="aba23" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba23);?>" class="form-control" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class= "col-md-1.5" align="centre">0.5M HCL</th>
<th class= "col-md-2" align="centre">60 Degree C</th>

<td><input type="datetime-local"  name="aba31" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba31);?>" class="form-control" ></td> 
<td><input type="datetime-local" name="aba32" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba32);?>" class="form-control" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="aba33" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba33);?>" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class= "col-md-1.5" align="centre">Freeze Drying</th>
<th class= "col-md-2" align="centre"> </th>
<td><input type="datetime-local"  name="aba41" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba41);?>" class="form-control" ></td> 
<td><input type="datetime-local" name="aba42" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba42);?>" class="form-control" ></td>
<td><input type="text" name="aba43" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba43);?>" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried it with the using if condition but i am not able to achieve it.Kindly suggest any clue or my mistake in this.I have entered the if condition only aba12.

Comment: I think typo error at  `$status12=enaabled;`

Comment: @VibhaChosla   Thanks it was mistake i already corrected it .

Comment: Do you want this on `page load` only or at input value change of first input ?

Comment: Page Load because after update the form saves the value

Comment: What are you getting in `htmlentities($result->aba12)`  ? Is your `$status11` is working when `$result->aba12` has a value ?

Comment: You need to use javascript instead of PHP, and make a function to enable/disable all the fields. You should use an event, like onchange or oninput

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified part of your code to do it. First of all, there is no way you can do it with PHP because it is executed before the page is loaded in the server side, so you will need to use javascript for this.

I have removed the PHP code for enabling/disabling the input elements. I made the solution just for the two first elements (you will have to do it for the rest, so when you get to the page, your `aba11` is enabled and the rest are disabled.
Once you set an input in `aba11` (as you have an event `oninput`), it calls the javascript function `disable_items` with a number (this number indicates wich of the fields we are working on.
The javascript function disables the actual element and enables the next one.

```
<td><input type="datetime-local"  oninput="disable_items(1)" name="aba11" id="aba11" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba11);?>" class="form-control" <?php echo $status11?> ></td> 

<td><input type="datetime-local" disabled oninput="disable_items(2)" name="aba12" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba12);?>" class="form-control" <?php echo $status12?>></td>
<td><input type="text" disabled name="aba13" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba13);?>" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class= "col-md-1.5" align="centre">0.0.1M NaOH</th>
<th class= "col-md-2" align="centre">60 Degree C</th>

<td><input type="datetime-local"  disabled name="aba21"onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba21);?>" class="form-control" ></td> 
<td><input type="datetime-local" disabled name="aba22" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba22);?>" class="form-control" ></td>
<td><input type="text" disabled name="aba23" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba23);?>" class="form-control" ></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class= "col-md-1.5" align="centre">0.5M HCL</th>
<th class= "col-md-2" align="centre">60 Degree C</th>

<td><input type="datetime-local"  disabled name="aba31" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba31);?>" class="form-control" ></td> 
<td><input type="datetime-local" disabled name="aba32" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba32);?>" class="form-control" ></td>
<td><input type="text" disabled name="aba33" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba33);?>" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th class= "col-md-1.5" align="centre">Freeze Drying</th>
<th class= "col-md-2" align="centre"> </th>
<td><input type="datetime-local" disabled name="aba41" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba41);?>" class="form-control" ></td> 
<td><input type="datetime-local" disabled name="aba42" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba42);?>" class="form-control" ></td>
<td><input type="text" disabled name="aba43" onkeydown="upperCaseF(this)" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->aba43);?>" class="form-control"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
function disable_items(option) {
    if (option==1){
        document.getElementById("aba11").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("aba12").disabled=false;
    }
    if (option==2){
        document.getElementById("aba12").disabled=true;
        document.getElementById("aba13").disabled=false;
    }   
}

</script>
```